# Replace character between strings

Tags: php, regex

Maybe it's just too late for me to do this, but I'm trying to replace a character between 2 string with regex in PHP.

Example string:

```
other | text [tag]text|more text|and more[/tag] end | text
```

My goal is to replace `|` with `<br/>` between `[tag]` and `[/tag]`.

Tried with this, seems it wasn't that easy though:

```
/<td>(\|)<td>/gsi
```

Searched a bit, but couldn't make out an answer with the stuff I found.

Hope you can help, thanks

Comment: It's hard to understand what you want to do.  Do you want to replace each occurence of the character _|_ that occurs between two occurrences of a given html tag?  And if so, are there guaranteed to only be two occurrences of the tag (or could there be 3, 4, etc...)?

Comment: @jahroy if i read this correctly, yes it is

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, find what's inside `[tag]`s, *then* find the pipes. PHP 5.3:

```
$result = preg_replace_callback('/\[tag\](.+?)\[\/tag\]/i', function($match) {
    return str_replace('|', '<br />', $match[1]);
}, $str);
```

Comment: thanks, found out the rest myself though, changed $match[1] to $match[0] as i want to keep the [tag]'s